# How to remove Tile Layers which is located out of visible region Google maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to delete all the titles are outside the visibility. I download titles from my server. To save memory, I want to delete the titles that are not visible

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {       
        let urls = { (x: UInt, y: UInt, zoom: UInt) -> NSURL in
            let url = "http://example.com/tiles/\(zoom)/\(x)/\(y).png"
            var dataOfTileXYZJson :Dictionary<NSString,UInt> = [:]
            dataOfTileXYZJson["dataOfTileX"] = x as UInt
            dataOfTileXYZJson["dataOfTileY"] = y as UInt
            dataOfTileXYZJson["dataOfTileZ"] = zoom as UInt
            JsonData.sendTilesCoordJsonToServer(dataOfTileXYZJson)
            dataOfTileXYZJson.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
            return NSURL(string: url)!
        }

        let visibleRegion : GMSVisibleRegion = viewMap.projection.visibleRegion()
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: visibleRegion.nearLeft, coordinate: visibleRegion.farRight)
        let layerTile = GMSURLTileLayer(URLConstructor: urls)
        layerTile.zIndex = 100
        layerTile.map = self.viewMap!
 }
```

But I can not figure out how to determine that the title does not fall into the zone of visibility.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your challenge is finding the bounding box for individual tiles. Google Maps works with the same projection (tiling scheme) as Open StreetMap so you can use their documentation to find the formulas you need.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_bounding_box

Take a look at the 'bounding box' calculation under the Java section. That should give you what you need to get the bounds of an individual tile. Once you have that you can use bounds.intersectsBounds(tileBounds) to determine if the tile falls within the visible region.